# Fortran class pointer to attribute - compiler dependent result

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
module my_class
   type, public :: my_object
      real, allocatable, private :: a(:)
      real, pointer :: b => null()
   end type my_object
   interface my_object
      module procedure :: init
   end interface my_object
contains
   function init () result ( self )
      type(my_object), target :: self
      allocate( self % a(2) )
      self % a = (/ 1.0, 2.0 /)
      self % b => self % a(1)
   end function init
end module my_class


program test
   use my_class
   type(my_object) :: object
   object = my_object()
   print *, associated( object % b )
   print *, "main: ", object % b
   object % b = 7.
   print *, "main: ", object % b
end program test
```

Attributes `a` and `b` are initialized in the class constructor. The expected result should be:

```
T
main: 1.00000000
main: 7.00000000
```

and this I get when I use a `gfortran 4.7.2` compiler, whereas code compiled with `ifort 13.0.1` produces the following result:

```
T
main:   1.1631523E+33
main:    7.000000
```

which I do not understand. Where I'm making an error?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in ifort 14.0.1 and got the same answer as gfortran. You may have encountered a compiler bug in the old version.

Comment: This is somewhat confusing to me that it even compiles.  `a` does not have target attribute and he is associating `b` to a member of array `a`.  Is this in anyway standard fortran?

Comment: `a` is not `target`, but the dummy argument `self` is. I don't know whether this is Standard Fortran, but it's working at least with `gfortran` and `ifort`. I use this feature a lot...

Comment: I have managed to upgrade ifort to 14.0.1 but the result is the same as later version.

Comment: It worked when I tried it. If you need more help, please ask in our user forum at http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not a bug, the code works fine, whereas the expected results are not right. In particular, the problem with your expected "main: 1.0000" result is due to the fact the function "init", that actually initializes array "a" (thus pointer "b") to 1.0,2.0 is never called by the main program. In the main program only the constructor "my_object()" is invoked, whereas "init" is not.

At least, this is my suggestion.

Comment: The constructor is overloaded by `init`, so init IS called at line `object = my_object()`.

Comment: I think that the my_object overloading is not realy working in the main program. In the main program, when object=my_object() is invoked, what it is really called is the non overloaded constructor or the assignment operator, if it is overloaded; to work as expected it is not enough to overload my_object, you should overload also the assignment operator. Please, note that in my comments there are not uppercase words... I do not scream...:-)

Comment: What makes you think so.  Maybe it is not called in @mmal's case, but then it is definitely a compiler bug or some even more weird bug somewhere else in his system.

Comment: Indeed, I think you have right. I have just seen that there is an associated check for pointer "b" in the main program, thus init must be invoked because "b" is initialized to null(). I have just installed GNU gfortran 4.8.2 and it works as exepected, whereas intel fortran 14.0.1 not. You are right: there is a bug in intel 14.0.1. I am sorry for my erroneous guess.